# How to fix 'unknown user 'redis' in statoverride file'

Tags: redis, installation, fatal-error, redis-server

I'm installing redis,  everytime I run this command `sudo apt install redis-server` I got an unrecoverable fatal error

I already tried many solutions to completly remove redis, redis-server, but nothing worked, this is the error

`dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown user 'redis' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I solved it by opening the statoverride file using

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

then removing the line with the user called "redis" along with any blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that ELTA gave didn't worked for me. In my case the unknown user was 'geoclue' when I opened the statoverride file using nano and removed the line containing geoclue and ran the apt command again then it gave the same error this time replacing geoclue with the first letter of the next line saying that '_gvm' is unknown user. So basically it jumps on the next line.

When I replaced geoclue with the existing user that I use to login, it simply ignores that line and jumps to next line saying '_gvm' is unknown user. I don't know if there's a solution for this on this planet.